# How to re-initialise jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin after first initialisation and subsequent remove()

Tags: jquery

I am using [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) and have wrapped it in a function that is called on a change event in a select dropdown using `on()`.

It works correctly on the first initialisation, but then fails to work after the div automatically created by the plugin has been removed via `remove()`.

Rather than use `remove()` I have also tried `detach()` in the hope that it would keep some plugin functionality that I wasn't able to see but that didn't work either.

**Plugin Function**

This generates a container div (`#image_path_wrap`) with several sub-divs.

It is triggered on an `on('change')` event linked to a select dropdown.

```
function initMultipleFileUpload() {
$('#image_path').MultiFile({
STRING: {
file: '<em title="Click to remove" onclick="$(this).parent().prev().click()">$file</em>',
remove: '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16/bdbdbd/ff0000&text=x" height="16" width="16" alt="x"/>'
}
});
}
```

**Remove Method**

This removes the automatically generated container div.

```
$("#image_path_wrap").remove();
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/RSbLc/

**Expected Behaviour**

The plugin should re-initialise (ie create the container div and sub-divs) the second time that the function is called via the select dropdown.

**Current Behaviour**

The plugin is failing to re-initialise the second time it is called via the select dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

When running the plugin it moves the initial input field into `#image_path_wrap`.

When removing `#image_path_wrap` the input field that the plugin is assigned to is also removed.

So after the `remove()` I re-appended the required input field.

```
var input_constructor = "<input type=\"file\" id=\"image_path\">";
$('label#image_paths_label').after(input_constructor);
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/RSbLc/42/